# What is this part of my shoulder called?

Tags: injury, injury-prevention, shoulders, rotator-cuff, shoulder-cuff

[image]

I am wondering if the red dot in the picture I took is my rotator cuff or what that part of my shoulder is called. I have been having a little pain in that spot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure this out for yourself by looking at a picture. Each individual part of the shoulder joint is too small for that red dot to give any indication of what/where the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Is the red dot part of the shoulder joint, or could it just be a pulled muscle?

Comment: That is impossible for us to know. The joint is behind the muscle. The red dot shows both.